# How can I do conditional compilation branching based on the real type used?

Tags: delphi, floating-point, cross-platform, floating-accuracy, conditional-compilation

I was doing a solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24498594) with respect to underlying hardware and platform.

Due Delphi's code generator specifics, it produces 80x87 instructions for IA32 platform and SSE instructions for AMD64 platform, thus having generic `Real` type defined as `Extended` or `Double` depending on the target.

The algorithm specifics requires some attention to be paid to the base type, because [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) differs for `Double` and `Extended` types. The only thing I figured out is branching on the size of function argument:

```
type
  Real = Extended{|Double|Single};

function SqrtHeron(a: Real): Real;
var
  x0: Real;
  x1: Real;
const
  FuzzFactor = 1000;
  {$IF SizeOf(a) = SizeOf(Extended)}
  Epsilon = 1E-19 * FuzzFactor;
  {$ELSE}{$IF SizeOf(a) = SizeOf(Double)}
  Epsilon = 1E-15 * FuzzFactor;
  {$ELSE}{$IF SizeOf(a) = SizeOf(Single)}
  Epsilon = 1E-7 * FuzzFactor;
  {$IFEND}{$IFEND}{$IFEND}
var
  n: Integer;
begin
  { ... }
```

How can I implement this branching in the better way? And I definitely want to avoid deceptively pretending `Double` machine epsilon for `Extended` machine epsilon (citing a clumsy patch to `Math.pas`):

```
const
  FuzzFactor = 1000;
  SingleResolution   = 1E-7 * FuzzFactor;
  DoubleResolution   = 1E-15 * FuzzFactor;
{$IFDEF CPUX64}
  ExtendedResolution = DoubleResolution;
{$ELSE !CPUX64}
  ExtendedResolution = 1E-19 * FuzzFactor;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Actually the generic `Real` type is always an alias to `Double`. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Real it's just your code in the Q that defines another alias named `Real`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your `{$IF}` statements can be cleaned up using `{$ELSEIF}` instead of `{$ELSE}{$IF}`.

Second, `Extended` and `Double` are the same thing on Win64, unless you enable [`{$EXTENDEDCOMPATIBILITY ON}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Extended_type_compatibility_%28Delphi%29), so your first `{$IF}` would end up using the wrong value.  Try swapping them to account for that.  I would even go as far as checking for `SizeOf(Single)` first, moving up in increasing byte size rather than down in decreasing size:

```
const
  FuzzFactor = 1000;
  {$IF SizeOf(Real) = SizeOf(Single)}
  Epsilon = 1E-7 * FuzzFactor;
  {$ELSEIF SizeOf(Real) = SizeOf(Double)}
  Epsilon = 1E-15 * FuzzFactor;
  {$ELSEIF (SizeOf(Extended) > SizeOf(Double)) and (SizeOf(Real) = SizeOf(Extended))}
  Epsilon = 1E-19 * FuzzFactor;
  {$IFEND}
```

If you need 80-bit precision on Win64, use [`TExtended80Rec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.TExtended80Rec) or [`TExtendedHelper`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.TExtendedHelper) instead.

Comment: So, no chances to escape examining byte sizes?

Comment: Not really, if you need to account for `Real` mapping to one of several different types based on platform. It is not like the multiplier can be simply calculated dynamically based on byte size, the values involved are not even multiples of the byte size.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea how `Math` contributors derived these resolution values, but that for the different question. Thanks!

Comment: @FreeConsulting: A Single has approx. 7 decimal digits resolution, a Double approx. 15 digits and an Extended approx. 19 digits. This can be established by taking the `log10(2^NumBitsInMantissa)`, where NumBitsInMantissa is 24, 53 and 64 respectively.